# Load char array into data table

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I Have been searching for several hours for a way to load my char array directly into a dynamic table and then into a data grid view.

Tried several approaches, but there's always something that's not working as planned.

Wanted: Array gets written into the table row wise, hopping from cell to cell.

```
private void btn_okay(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //reading the strings from the two text boxes 
    Char[] ArrayUp = rtb_up.Text.ToCharArray();
    Char[] ArrayDown = rtb_down.Text.ToCharArray();
    Char[] ArrayEnd = new Char [ArrayUp.Length * ArrayDown.Length];

    //comparison of the two char arrays and filling the new char array
    Int32 I = 0;

    for (Int32 C = 0; C < ArrayDown.Length; C++)
    {
       for (Int32 D = 0; D < ArrayUp.Length; D++)
        {
            if (ArrayDown[C] == ArrayUp[D])
            {
                ArrayEnd[I] = '+' ;
                I ++;
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayEnd[I] = '-'  ;
                I ++;
            }
        }
    }

    //creation of data table
    DataTable Table = new DataTable();

    for (Int32 E = 0; E < ArrayUp.Length; E++)
        Table.Columns.Add("", typeof(Char));

    for (Int32 R = 0; R < ArrayDown.Length; R++)
        Table.LoadDataRow(ArrayEnd[R], LoadOption.OverwriteChanges()); 

    //OverwriteChanges won't work
    dgv_main.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dgv_main.DataSource = Table;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
string arrayUp = "ABBAAAABABAAAB"; // Example value for rtb_up.Text
string arrayDown = "ABABAAABAB"; // Example value for rtb_down.Text

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

// Add variable number of columns, depending on the length of arrayUp
for (int i = 0; i < arrayUp.Length; i++)
    dataTable.Columns.Add("");

// Iterate through the "rows" first
for (int i = 0; i < arrayDown.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

    // Then iterate through the "columns"
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayUp.Length; j++)
    {
        if (arrayDown[i] == arrayUp[j])
            dataRow[j] = "+";
        else
            dataRow[j] = "-";
    }

    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}

dgv_main.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgv_main.DataSource = dataTable;
```

This will give you a plot exactly like the screenshot you posted - wherever an A or B intersect, there will be a plus sign (+).  Where they don't intersect, there will be a minus sign (-).

It's important to note that a string is essentially a Char[], so there is not need to cast your TextBox value as a Char[].

Does that get you what you need?

Comment: That's not exactly solving my problem. I want to load the char array into an either existing table or one that gets created while the storing array gets filled. The number or rows and columns isn't static otherwise I probably would have less drama.

Comment: My examples don't require that the number of rows or number of columns are static.  The number of rows or columns depends entirely on the length of the array.  In your case, it would be the length of `rtb_up.Text` or `rtb_down.Text`.  I filled my array with specific values for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: It may help to see some example values that would be stored in both the `ArrayUp` and `ArrayDown` arrays - and how you'd like to see those in your DataGridView.

Comment: I didn't say that your examples require that but a lot of others I've seen so far. 
Neither ArrayUp nor ArrayDown are stored there, it's ArrayEnd, the array that gets filled via those two loops. In that array, there are only + or - and they are supposed to be at special positions. Kind of like this here: http://www-lehre.img.bio.uni-goettingen.de/Bio_Inf/dotplot/dotplot.gif

Applied your idea but it only fills one line and not as many lines needed to get all data in. Probably something simple that's not working yet. It always is. ;)

Comment: DataTable Table = new DataTable();

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < ArrayUp.Length ; i++)
                Table.Columns.Add(i + ArrayUp[i].ToString());

            DataRow dataRow = Table.NewRow();

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < ArrayDown.Length; i++)
                dataRow[i] = ArrayEnd[i];

            Table.Rows.Add(dataRow);

            dgv_main.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgv_main.DataSource = Table;

Comment: Aha - I see.  I will modify my answer to reflect what you are looking for.